# Wordpress post type for single page (without posts list)

Tags: custom-post-types

I was wondering if you can change "the type" of a wordpress custom post type. So: when I create a custom post type to somehow remove the post list:[image] and jump directly to the edit page...

I am trying to do this because I got a section on my page where arent any posts. Only one section whose content changes...[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is real page, which display for the end users as web page, you can play with 'page'. Basically CPT is kind of archive which means a set of posts. If the purpose of your request is for the part of page, it might be closer to term meta than page.

Comment: You can create a custom post type that has no archive - if the problem is there's an archive you don't want displayed. But it does sound like postmeta - or even perhaps some Customizer code - would work better than creating this content as a post of any type.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the functionalities of a post, you could just simply create an admin menu by the add_menu_page function. In the callback function, you can write the normal php code to display and edit the title and description part. It would be a lot more convenient method.